# Extracting features/ labels from .wav file to .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, voice-recognition

I need to extract features such as duration, meanfreq, sd, median,... from a .wav file (audio sample) to a .csv file.

I have already completed the code but I cant manage to get all features that I need.
The features I would like to have is:

```
"meanfreq", "sd", "median", "Q25", "Q75", "IQR", "skew", "kurt", "sp.ent", "sfm", "mode", "centroid", "meanfun", "minfun", "maxfun", "meandom", "mindom", "maxdom", "dfrange", "modindx", "label"
```

The features that I have managed to extract are:

```
'nobs', 'mean', 'skew', 'kurtosis', 'median', 'mode', 'std', 'low', 'peak', 'q25', 'q75', 'iqr', 'label'
```

this is my function that I have finished (note: this is only a small part of my code for features, I have more):

```
def get_features(frequencies):  # acoustic attributes
    print("\nExtracting features ")
    nobs, minmax, mean, variance, skew, kurtosis = 
    stats.describe(frequencies)
    median = np.median(frequencies)
    mode = stats.mode(frequencies).mode[0]
    std = np.std(frequencies)
    low, peak = minmax
    q75, q25 = np.percentile(frequencies, [75, 25])
    iqr = q75 - q25
    return (nobs, mean, skew, kurtosis, median, mode, std, low, peak, q25, q75, iqr)
```

I am also aware that there are existing voice.csv datasets on the internet, but I would like the code for converting them from .wav to .csv and be able to extract the features myself rather than to use a preprocessed .csv file.

Thank you so much in advance:)

Comment: have you found one ? cuz I am looking for same thing

Comment: You are not mentioning the excellent [`librosa`](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/). Is there a reason for not using it? IMHO, this is one of the best tools to handle audio. It doesn't preclude you from using `numpy` as well, but there are many features you will love for feature extraction. And it does many other things (FFT, spectrograms, Mel-cepstral coefficients, etc.)